# How can I iteratively add elements to a list

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, date-and-time, mathematica-online, iteration

Basically I want to make a histogram with a list of dates by using DateHistogram[]. However I have the data of the dates in nested list format, with elements like `{2020,6,26}`, and although I know how to convert it to a date by using `DateObject[{2020,6,26}]` I can not construct a list of dates by iteration. I am trying the following:

```
For[i = 0, i < 5, i++, Insert[egunak, DateObject[watchdates[[i]]], 1]]
```

where `watchdates` is the nested list of `{2020,6,26}` date elements and `egunak` is the list I want to create with the dates (I have tried it to define it before).

I have also tried using `Append` instead of Insert or by iterating with `Do`, but didn't succeed. I am pretty new with the Wolfram language, sorry.

Comment: Is `egunak = watchdates[[;;4]]` what you are looking for?

Comment: Be sure to check out `AppendTo` and compare it with `Append`. Also, `Do` is better than `For` because it's less error prone, but functional solutions like `Map` is the best of all in almost all situations. (Easier to read and has better performance.)

Comment: I see, alright thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 6):

You can `Map` the `DateObject[]` function onto each member of your `watchdates` list like in

```
Map[DateObject, {{2020, 6, 26}, {2020, 6, 25}}]
```

which yields a list of `DateObjects`.

There is also a shorter symbolic form for `Map`

```
DateObject /@ {{2020, 6, 26}, {2020, 6, 25}}
```

Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Yeeees!! that exactly what I wanted. I didn't know about the Map function